sudo apt-get update error in UBUNTU 23.10
My ubuntu version is 23.10
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu mantic Release
404 Not Found [IP: **]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Could you please help? I have been trying to solve this for a long time.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This version of Ubuntu has reached end of support, hence you get this error. You need to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 (supported until 2029). While it is possible to upgrade to this new version from your (unsupported) release, many people are facing serious issues (like graphical interface gone) in the upgrade path. I recommend that you download Ubuntu 24.04, flash it in a USB, and boot from the USB drive, and fresh install. Before installation, backup all files in your home partition.

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

After a release goes EOL the main archives is moved as per EOLUpgrades or the duplicate link, and mirrors are free to drop support for the EOL release. That is expected, the only thing unknown is how long after the EOL does it occur; with 17.04 that was the following day or 1 day after, yet on more recent releases this occurs after weeks (the EOL notice specifically said "coming weeks") and won't change, as the EOL status is permanent (as release notes for 23.10 said on its release too).
